# Display ajax called data in a table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this ajax call that gets a json array from the PHP file. I need to put the data into rows in a table which in #gamesList.

I have the append I just do not know how to go through the returned json array and put them in the append

```
$("#ALL").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getGames.php',
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data:({btn:'ALL' }),
            success:function(data){
                //get returned list of games
                //Loop through games
                //display games in table
                $( "#gamesList").append('<tr><td>name</td><td>M</td><td>(2)Entries</td><td>(5)max people</td><td>($100)Fee</td><td>Prizes</td><td>7:00PM(start)</td></tr>');
            }
        });

    }); //btn click
```

PHP File it returns the rows

```
$res = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM games");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $games[] = $row;
 }
   echo json_encode($games)
```

Comment: you need to show json response

Comment: Sounds like a job for a loop!  Hard to tell without some response information.

Comment: `$.each(data, function(i,v){ console.log(i +' : '+ v); });` start with that.

Comment: [{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"Namee one Heree","name" Namee one Heree","2":"1","league_type":"1","3":"1","multiple":"1","4":"0","entries":"0","5":"10","max":"10","6":"5","fee":"5","7":"40","prizes":"40","8":"2014-10-17","start":"2014-10-17"}]

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo the result with html and not JSON. View below edits and comments

```
$("#ALL").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getGames.php',
        type:"POST",
        //changed from json to html
        dataType:'html',
        data:({btn:'ALL' }),
        success:function(data){
            //display games table echoed from php file inside div gametable
            $("#gamesList").html(data);
        }
    });

    //stop normal form submission
    return false;

    }); //btn click
```

For the php file you make a slight change and run it through a loop

```
$res = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM games");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
//$games[] = $row;
}?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($res as $game){?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $game['TABLE_COLUMN_NAME'];?>
<td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

each $game is a row in your DB table. This code will echo out a table with all the rows and dump that content of this php file into the gamesList div.

Hope this helps!

-Nick

Comment: Ah question just to understand the 

for <?php foreach ($games as $game){?>

where and how is the games array set?

Comment: @pschemm031 Sorry. I updated the answer. You are using deprecated MYSQL and I cannot for the life of me remember how it works. I actually use a class now which makes life so much easier. https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#update-query

Comment: Its ok i figured it out!